# Running bash sript which runs pkill -f using sudo, taking the password automatically

Tags: bash

I want to be able run a bash script which calls another command `sudo pkill -f "test.py"`.

1. How can I do this in a way the password will be taken automatically during command launch?
2. Is there a way of hiding my password out of being able to see it in the script in some `****` manner?

Comment: you'd have to embed the PW in your script, which means it's easily accesible. why not just make `pkill` no-pw-required in sudo instead?

Comment: @marcB: How would you do that?

Comment: No, don't store passwd in any plain text file, it's a very bad practice. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Better don't use any password at all just for a particular root script by using `sudo` properly. :

all as root :

create a script with :

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/pkill -f "test.py"
```

put it in `/path/to/script`

```
chmod 700 /path/to/script
chown root:root /path/to/script
```

Type `visudo` as root, then by example :

```
# /etc/sudoers
# blah...

yourusername ALL = (ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

Then,

```
sudo /path/to/script
```